# python - Stacked Classifier: IndexError while fitting the data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I am using bank data to predict number of tickets on a daily basis. I am using stacking to get more accurate result and using [brew](https://github.com/viisar/brew) library.

Here is the sample dataset for important features:

[[image]]
Here is the target attribute sample:

[[image]]

Here is the code:

```
from stacked_generalization.lib.stacking import StackedClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
# Stage 1 model
bclf = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)

# Stage 0 models
clfs = [RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40, criterion = 'gini', random_state=1),
        gbm,
        RidgeClassifier(random_state=1)]

sl = StackedClassifier(bclf, clfs)
sl.fit(training.select_columns(features).to_dataframe().as_matrix(), np.array(training['class']))
```

Here is the training data format:

```
[[  21   11 2014   46    4    3]
 [  22   11 2014   46    5    4]
 [  24   11 2014   47    0    4]
 ..., 
 [  30    9 2016   39    4    5]
 [   3   10 2016   40    0    1]
 [   4   10 2016   40    1    1]]
```

Now, when I try to fit the model, it gives the following error: 
[image]

However, I compared my code with the example given in the library but still couldn't figure out where am I going wrong. Kindly assist me.

Comment: What is the format of the training object?

Comment: updated my answer, first it was in sframe then I converted it to numpy nd array

Comment: The error is with array indexing. `c.classes_` is a nested list or a list of something other than integers or booleans. Are they strings by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and seems to just be a bug in brew that needs to be fixed.  The problem is that the c.classes_ (or number of classes) returns a numpy array with floats (e.g., if you have two classes it returns [0.0, 1.0] instead of integers ([0,1]).  The code tries to use these floats to index the columns, but you cannot index a numpy column with floats.

probas.shape = # rows = # training examples; # columns = # of classes

`c.predict_proba(X)` returns probabilites for each class for each training example.

```
probas[:, list(c.classes_)] = c.predict_proba(X)
```

Should put the probability for each class for each row in X into probas using class # to index columns in probas.

This would work if you add astype(int)

`probas[:, list(et.classes_.astype(int))] = et.predict_proba(X)`

or just

```
probas = np.copy(et.predict_proba(X))
```